# Android Table Layout with Scrollview does not fit the parents width

Tags: android, android-layout

I'm working on an App, which contains a Table Layout in a Scrollview.
I want the Table to fill the  width of the screen, but I don't really now what to do.

I tried to first set the scrollView to fill_parent, but then I get dozens of "unhandled event loop exceptions". And about three "Invalid preference page path: XML Syntax" Errors.

If I just try to set the table layout to fill_parent just nothing happens.
Here is an excerpt of my "scroll-table construction"

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNew"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="New" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnDelete"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.20"
        android:text="Delete" />
</LinearLayout>


<ScrollView
    android:id="@+id/scrollView1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_weight="0.20" >

    <TableLayout
        android:id="@+id/tableLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >

        <TableRow
            android:id="@+id/tableRow1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="@drawable/cell_shape2"
                android:padding="5dp"
                android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceSmall" />
```

... etc. (much stuff not necessary).

I hope you can give me a hint, because I really don't know why my scrollview can't fit the parent width and I don't know, if it would help, if it would fit.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you're using Eclipse, try to use menu Project -> Clean... -> (select your project) -> Press OK. This is sometimes needed to recompile the xml resources when you've changed something.

Also, I don't think you can have a both a LinearLayout and a ScrollView in the root of an XML-layout.

If you'd like the columns content to fill you probably need to set

```
android:stretchColumns="1"
```

on the TableLayout, and

```
android:layout_column="1"
```

on the TextView.

You could also try and use

```
android:fillViewport="true"
```

on the ScrollView.

Comment: Okay thanks, the error is gone, but if i set both elements to match_parent the Table is still just as big as the text in columns.

Comment: thanks, the stretchColumns worked ! 
I thought i have to use match_parant... anyway Problem solfed and thank you very much!

i really would like to vote your answer up... damn reputation...

Comment: I also found that setting a Weight of 1 on my table fixed it.